# Text not visible when renaming files and folders in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, themes, ubuntu-gnome, gtk3

When I am renaming files and folders in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, the text is not visible. Is there any way to fix this?

Just realized that this problem seems to appear only when "View items as a grid of icons" option is selected. The other one "View items as a list" option works fine.

[image: View items as a grid of icons]

[image: View items as a list]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using the default theme (Adwaita) for Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.

This issue is frustrating, however, there is a workaround. Please note that it is not possible to make it identical to the **View items as a list** option view.

Firstly, open up the terminal and enter this command:

```
cp -a /usr/share/themes/Adwaita/ ~/.themes/custom
```

After that open up your browser and visit this link: [GTK Github](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk).

Then click on the **Clone or download** button, then click **Download Zip**. After the zip is downloaded, extract it and then you will get a directory named `gtk-master`.

After that open up terminal and run this command:

```
cp -a ~/Downloads/gtk-master/gtk/theme/Adwaita/* ~/.themes/Custom/gtk-3.0/
```

Then enter this command:

```
sudo -H gedit ~/.themes/custom/gtk-3.0/nautilus-entry-section.css
```

This will open gedit with a newly created file named `nautilus-entry-section.css`. Inside that file add the following code:

```
NautilusCanvasViewContainer.view EelEditableLabel.entry{
color: black;
background: #3F90ED
}

NautilusCanvasViewContainer.view EelEditableLabel.entry:selected {
color: white;
}

.nautilus-desktop.nautilus-canvas-item {
color: white;
}
```

Save and exit the file.

*It is to be noted that you can change the color styling according to your preferences. The `background: #3F90ED;` line makes the background of the typing area to blue while `color: white;` and `color: black;`makes the font color of the text to white and black respectively. You can change them according to your liking. For example, you can make the background to white and text color to black when it is not selected and blue when it is selected. To do so, just change the content of `nautilus-entry-section.css` file accordingly.*

After you have saved and exited the `nautilus-entry-section.css` file, next you are going to edit the `gtk.css` file. For that enter the following command:

```
gedit ~/.themes/custom/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

This opens up gedit with the `gtk.css` file open. Enter the following line to the end of the file:

```
@import url("nautilus-entry-section.css");
```

Save and exit.

To apply the modified theme, open up the **Tweak Tool**, then click on **Extensions** tab, scroll down and enable the extension **User themes**. Exit the **Tweak Tool**. Again open up **Tweak Tool**, then in the **Appearance** tab under the **Theme** section, make **GTK+** use the **Custom** theme.

Now the problem is solved, and the text is readable. Again, if you don't like the color, change it according to your liking, however you will not be able to make it identical like the "View items as a list" option view. I have tried my best. Note that this is a workaround not a fix.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of the used gtk-theme, simply choose another one, e.g. Radiant-MATE, which is part of the package ubuntu-mate-themes.